# django models date day is filtered to the day before

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with a DateTimeField, and I have set it to Nov 20 2017

```
In [23]: my_obj.date_field
Out[23]: datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 20, 0, 0, 1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

But when I try to retrieve by selecting the objects with `date_field`'s day = 20, Django does not find the element

```
In [11]: MyObj.objects.filter(date_field__day=20)
Out[11]: <QuerySet []>
```

However, if I select the elements with `date_field`'s day = 19, it does find my object.

```
In [12]: Regime.objects.filter(start_date__day=19)
Out[12]: <QuerySet [my_obj]>
```

Can someone explain this weird behavior? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Is your app timezone aware? If it is, it might be because of the timezone setting.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a time zone issue, since your time is set to `0, 0, 1`.

Your own timezone is not UTC, so Django is right to tell you that no object belongs to *your* day of Nov 20.

Depending on your app, this may or may not be the intended behaviour. For example, if you are tracking forum posts, than it makes sense to see things in your timezone and not the other.

And if you want to avoid all that, since you named your field "date_field", I'm assuming you don't care about time, so just use a `DateField` instead of a `DateTimeField`.